# Primera letra en mayúsculas

Tags: css

Tengo una tabla que realizo una consulta de usuarios, en el cual cada registro tiene un campoo name y naturalmente estan todos los nombres en mayusculas

Ejemplo:

`JUAN DOMINGO VARGAS ROSETTI`

Quiero poder hacer con el CSS en el frontend que solamente me deje la primera letra de cada nombre en mayúsculas.

Como me gustaria verlo:

`Juan Domingo Vargas Rosetti`

**Como puedo realizar esto?**

Estuve probando con el pseudo elemento `::first-letter`, pero no doy con la tecla.

Muchas gracias.

Saludos

Comment: Échale un vistazo a esto https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471157/css-text-transform-capitalize-on-all-caps. Aparentemente no hay manera de hacerlo con CSS, deberás utilizar otros métodos como dentro de PHP (o lo que estés usando, Python, perl, CGI, ASP, etc) o con Javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si tu texto va a ocupar una sola línea y no más, se me ocurre un pequeño truco para conseguirlo solamente con **CSS**, de no ser así deberías hacer uso de **Javascript**.

Ya que la propiedad `text-transform: capitalize` afecta solamente a la primera letra de cada palabra (dejando el resto tal como están) la idea es volver primero todas minúsculas para poder posteriormente aplicarle el `capitalize`.

```css
p {
  text-transform: lowercase;
}

p::first-line {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<p>JUAN DOMINGO VARGAS ROSETTI</p>
```

La magia se encuentra en que mediante el pseudo-elemento `::first-line` podemos afectar a parte del `<p>` por lo que el navegador considera que no estamos sobreescribiendo la propiedad `text-transform` y nos permite aplicarle ambas transformaciones al mismo elemento.

Comment: Perfecto!: Es lo que necesito.
Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score -1):

Una respuesta sería hacerlo con php:

**Para hacer ejemplo recuerda tener xamp instalado y que el archivo prueba.php esté en la carpeta Disco Local (C:)/xamp/htdocs/Pruebas**

```
    //RECIBIMOS EL TEXTO EN MAYÚSCULA
    $textomayusculas = "ESTA ES UNA PRUEBA PARA CAMBIAR LAS LETRAS";
    //modificamos texto a minúsculas con la función de PHP strtolower()
    $textominusculas = strtolower($textomayusculas);
    //modificamos texto a una mayúscula con la función de PHP ucwords()
    $textounamayuscula = ucwords($textominusculas);
```

//prueba.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sin título</title>

    
</head>
    
    

<body>
    
    
    <?php
        //RECIBIMOS EL TEXTO EN MAYÚSCULA
        $textomayusculas = "ESTA ES UNA PRUEBA PARA CAMBIAR LAS LETRAS";
        //modificamos texto a minúsculas con la función de PHP strtolower()
        $textominusculas = strtolower($textomayusculas);
        //modificamos texto a una mayúscula con la función de PHP ucwords()
        $textounamayuscula = ucwords($textominusculas);
    
    ?>
    
    <div>
        <p><?php echo ucwords($textounamayuscula); ?></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, realiza solo una respuesta, si tienes cambios editala, revisa [answer].